# Out Of Memory in Codename One

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, codenameone

My app used the SidePanel menu as navigation and when I show new form or open sidebar panel, the app takes more and more memory. Possible, it depended on using some Image processing (to mask image to circle) in SideBar and a lot of using URLImage class for downloading images. But most likely due to the fact that I did not free memory of the previous form.

*How I can free this memory?*

Code of changing forms:

```
public void showForm(FormBuilder form) {
    if ( current == null ||
         ( ! form.getForm().getTitle().equals(current.getTitle()) )
    ) {
        current = form.getForm();
        if (!(form instanceof splash)) {
            try {
                sideMenu.addMenu(current);
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }
        current.show();
    }
}
```

**void sideMenu.addMenu(Form form);** - Static function for add SideBar menu to form.

Answer (score 2):

Previous forms "should" be GC'd. However, if you have a reference to one element in the previous form the whole form and all its content will be kept. This is because every component has a reference to its parent all the way up to the parent form.

You can use tools like the NetBeans memory profiler and also our [performance profiler](http://www.codenameone.com/performance--network-monitor.html) tool in NetBeans to track down memory usage. Image masking is a bit expensive but if you used the one built into `URLImage` all the memory overhead is GC'd so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This tool has a lot of troubles. If I call Performance or Network monitors - emulation window of my app may be is not clickable. Or vice versa - Emulator works fine, but monitor do not clickable.
However, performance monitor showed me this memory overflow and nothing else what I could understand.

Comment: The window shouldn't block click ability, its always on top but not modal. On which OS/Java version are you experiencing this?

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: Its possible that the Gnome port didn't implement the AWT on top API correctly. Ugh. I'm not exactly sure how we can workaround that properly. Did you try the netbeans memory profiler? It should point out which object is held and where is the reference to it kept.

Comment: No, don't tried. But trouble was solved when I generated all components in splash screen. However, leaks were only side bar menu, but it's not critical.