# Avoiding out of memory in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I am in the same situation as the one depicted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013092/out-of-memory-in-codename-one). Indeed my app relies massively on `URLImage` and also uses SidePanel for navigation. After a while it becomes unusable because of OOM thrown when I press the back button (Android).

So I need advices to avoid these OOM errors. A first advice was given in the above mentionned question, that is to not pass reference to any element from the previous form.

Indeed I was passing the whole form because I wanted to know from where the "generic" next form was called (to know where to go when the user clicks on the back button). So I changed that and now pass the Form's class (`myForm.getClass()`). However the performance monitor still shows more than 200 MB as "image memory overhead".

So maybe the problem is elsewhere since I need to also pass custom objects. Indeed I have a form A which lists all Reports in an InfiniteScrollAdapter. The Reports are fetched from a server. Then when the user clicks on a row, it opens the selected Report details (date, image, location, ...) in another form (B), and finally if the user clicks on the image or on the location it opens another form with the image in big size or a Google Map of the location.

If it is not possible to pass in those Reports, how can I do, or does the problem really come from these passed in references ?

Any help really appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using problematic images and too many of those without releasing them. A good tool to use is a memory profiler, I use the one in NetBeans which allows you to dig thru the allocation stack and see which code allocates which memory block.

I'd also suggest reading about the various types of images in the [developer guide graphics section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html) and the [performance section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/performance-debugging.html) (which discusses memory too). To sum this up make sure your images are sized correctly and are `EncodedImage` or a variation of those. You might want to `unlock()` unused encoded images so the GC can act more aggressively on them.

Once you narrow the leak to a specific set of images it should be much easier to give specific advice on how to manage this.

Comment: Ok thanks Shai for the guide. I'll have a look at the developer guide again ;-). FYI the used images are low quality ones (less than 200k). But I'll make sure they are all EncodedImage because I haven't paid attention to this so far. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: During my inquiry about that OOM, I came across this oddity : if I launch my app without splashscreen when the app shows the next form (main form) it needs ~90MB of "image memory overhead". But if I launch it with splashscreen, then when the main form is shown, the app required now 120MB of "image memory overhead". The only thing all my forms share is the theme resource that each form receives from the previous one. Is the theme considered as a reference to an element to the previous form ?

Comment: On the main form I have a map above which I add a transparent radar image png (width = height = 4000 px) of 3MB. It has been imported as a multiimage. If I remove it then the image memory overhead settles down to ~60MB on the main form, and the OOM is gone on the device. @Shai do you think it is worth it to draw the radar manually (`Graphics`, ...) ?

Comment: There are several things that might trigger this. A multi image is in RAM only in one resolution but in the res file it is stored in many resolutions and the res file might be loaded over and over again triggering this overhead. Are you calling stuff like `Resources.open` or something like this?

Comment: Not calling `Resources.open` only `theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");` in the `init` method.

Comment: Did you run with a profiler? What is the resolution of the image you receive? Is it locked? Which image type is it (class name)? Are there more than one copy of it in RAM?

Comment: Sorry I did not find the profiler so I found the workaround to remove that big image from the `Form` and from the `theme` res file. Eventually the design is better, since the Google maps look pretty good. The image was initially 4000 x 4000 because I wanted it to look good on HD+ screens. I did not play with lock/unlock() and I used it like `radarImage[0] = EncodedImage.createFromImage(theme.getImage("Radar.png"), false); // png required for transparency`. Now that it has been removed, the app runs smoother and the image memory overhead is around 100MB. I will try the profiler when I've time!

Comment: It might work better without `createFromImage` you can just downcast to encoded image in the case of images returned from multi-image. 4000x4000 might be a bit much...